# What is the coupling of two measures?

Tags: definition

I know what means coupling for random variables, as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28probability%29).

But what is a coupling of measures?

Comment: I would guess that it is still defined through their corresponding r.v.s

Answer (score 0):

A coupling of two measures $\mu,\nu\ $ is a measure on the product space with marginals $\mu,\nu\ $. See defintion 1.1 (and discussion below) in [here](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf).